# Cycle table and Parts table relashionship

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

There's this book from Microsoft, for MTA Exam having the following question:

What is a good foreign key for the relationship between the cycle table and the parts table?

```
a. part number
b. cycle model number
c. part name
```

and the given answer is (a. part number)

I believe it should be (b. cycle model number) since many parts will refer to one cycle model. and the cycle number will be stored in the parts table.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: `Cycle model number` sure makes more sense to me...

Comment: printing errors have been known to happen... in fact, I would probably design a many to many relationship since each model is made out of multiple parts but each part might also belong to multiple models...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is correct, part_number should be the foreign key

CYCLE_TABLE would have

cycle_model_number as primary key and
part_number as foreign key to PARTS table

where PARTS_TABLE would have

part_number as primary key

> since many parts will refer to one cycle model. and the cycle number
>   will be stored in the parts table.

sample data

CYCLE_TABLE

```
cycle_model_number    part_number
CM1000                P10A
CM1000                P10B
CM1000                P20A
CM1000                P22C
```

PARTS_TABLE

```
part_number     part_description
P10A            description for P10A
P10B            description for P10B
P20A            description for P20A
P22C            description for P22C
```